# OutofmemoryError: PermGen on play 2.2.2

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, typesafe-activator

I created a simple play project (hello-play) using activator (Typesafe Activator 1.1.1).

My `sbt` script looks like

```
SBT_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M" java $SBT_OPTS -jar `dirname $0`/sbt-launch.jar "$@"
```

When I run sbt play my server starts correctly on localhost:9000. However when I make a simple change to one of my scala sources and click on the page again, it gives me the following error.

NOTE: I'm not sure if this is the correct way to run a play app from the command line when it was initially created using activator.

```
$sbt play
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/ssimanta/hello-play/project
[info] Set current project to hello-play (in build file:/Users/ssimanta/hello-play/)
       _
 _ __ | | __ _ _  _
| '_ \| |/ _' | || |
|  __/|_|\____|\__ /
|_|            |__/

play 2.2.2 built with Scala 2.10.3 (running Java 1.7.0_45), http://www.playframework.com

> Type "help play" or "license" for more information.
> Type "exit" or use Ctrl+D to leave this console.

[hello-play] $ run

--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/ssimanta/hello-play/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[info] play - Application started (Dev)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/ssimanta/hello-play/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] application - 

! Internal server error, for (GET) [/message] ->

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.take(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:196) ~[na:na]
    at sbt.Execute.next$1(Execute.scala:88) ~[na:na]
    at sbt.Execute.processAll(Execute.scala:91) ~[na:na]
    at sbt.Execute.runKeep(Execute.scala:69) ~[na:na]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
```

Comment: What was the "simple change" that you made?

Comment: I changed the string returned by one of the controllers method `getMessage`

Answer (score 0):

The default value for `MaxPermSize` on my installation is 512 MB. I think this amount of memory may be required, especially for some templates.

Try changing your `SBT_OPTS` to include
`-XX:MaxPermSize=512M`.

Comment: Increasing it to 512 results in the same PermGen error.